Do you recognize this algebraic structure?
Let $S$ be a totally ordered finite set and $n=|S|$. Define $$ \Pi_k(S) = \left \langle X.A \mid A \in {S \choose k} , X \subseteq S \setminus A \right \rangle_\mathbb{Z} $$ and $$ \Pi(S) = \bigoplus_{k=0}^n \Pi_k(S).$$
I interpret its elements as (linear combinations of) the $k$-faces of an $n$-cube:

$\emptyset.\emptyset$ is some chosen vertex which serves as the base
In $X.A$, $X$ is a face that has the base as anchor point. Its vertex that is farthest from the base serves as anchor point for the $k$-face $A$.

Now I noticed that this has actually a module structure $X \cdot (Y.A) = (X \cup Y.A)$ if $X \subseteq A^C$ and $0$ else. Using this, we can define a chain complex structure on $\Pi(S)$. But I am not very happy with the above construction, as I feel there is something more familiar hidden (like an exterior algebra module or so). Note that we could have also defined the elements in $\Pi(S)$ as linear combinations of partitions $X \sqcup A \sqcup Y$ of $S$.
My question is: Have you seen this algebraic structure before? Do you see a less artificial way do define it?

What does $X.A$ mean? What does $A^C$ mean? You say module structure, over which ring?

$X.A$ is just a symbol. One could also write $(X,A) \in P(S) \times P(S)$. $A^C=S \setminus A$.

I guess the underlying ring is the monoid ring $\mathbb{Z}[P(S)]$ over the commutative monoid $P(S)$

Why the downvote?

Should your condition be $X\subset A^C$ for the action by $\mathcal{P}(S)$? $Y\subset A^C$ is true by definition.

Ah yes, thx. I'll edit it
